# How to make page in Main-Bar hidden to everyone but Admins?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

[image: Picture Example]

Pretty much self explanatory, because if i put [Authorize (Roles="Admin")], page is still visible in main bar, and i want it to be hidden from everyone unless logged in as Admin.

Comment: you need to put an if in the code that makes the nav and check on the role type of the current user - show the link if it is admin.  But this question is too broad and therefore off topic for SO.  Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Comment: where did you put `[Authorize (Roles="Admin")]`? on the controller method? how did the menu generated..?

Comment: If you put the authorise attribute on the controller action which renders the "Contact" page then that's good because it stops non-admins accessing it manually by the URL instead of clicking on the link. So don't take that away. But the hyperlink in the menu is a totally separate thing. For that as Pete says, you need to put an `if` in the Razor code of the view to check the user's current role, and decide whether to include that link in the page or not based on whether they are in the Admin role or not.

Comment: I put [Authorize (Roles="Admin")] behind Contact is HomeController, im not sure where and what to do to make the whole thing invisible in Main Bar, not only to restrict access to that page. Basically im making my first school project so im not "an expert" if you know what i mean, so i would appreciate if someone could show me a bit deeper where and how to generate "if" with such checks.

Comment: Well, you have some HTML which makes the "contacts" link appear, yes? You need to put an `if` statement round that using Razor code.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is i don't really know how to properly generate that IF check, this is what i had in mind:  https://imgur.com/a/d1B02o6

Comment: yes that's the general idea. You likely need an @ before the `if` - check the syntax for Razor blocks. Plus you probably want User.IsInRole()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In _Layout.cshtml you'll need to make the following change:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
        @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty much all i had to do, it works !!